# How is a hoverboard powered in Back to The Future?

Tags: back-to-the-future

How is a hoverboard powered? Where is the fuel? How does it detect the kicking action to accelerate at start?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The same way a skateboard is powered, by the person riding it. The "standard" hoverboard like the one that Marty rode (which if you remember was actually a scooter he broke down into a hoverboard), as well as all the others (with the exception of Griff's Pitbull board that had rockets), work just like a regular skateboard.  The difference being that instead of wheels it uses two powerful magnets (the flat metallic disks on the bottom roughly where the trucks and wheels on a skateboard would be) In reality this would require an opposing magnetic force to keep the board and rider floating, but that's a different question to answer ("Would a hoverboard really work?")

Side note: Mattel actually *did* try and make a working hoverboad shortly after *Back to the Future II* came out, the father of a girl I went to grade school with was on the design team.  I think the plan was to use fans on the bottom like a hovercraft but they never got the project... "off the ground" *badum tish!*

Comment: See a 'prototype' [here](http://gizmodo.com/5549271/a-real-working-hoverboard-exists).

Comment: That sounds like something a dad would tell a daughter to troll her.

Comment: Yeah, really.  I don't think a group of engineers roaring with laughter qualifies as "trying to make a working hoverboard."

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue of how they work in-universe

Answer (score 12):

I haven't found an official explanation how Hoverboards work, but according to [**Futurepedia**](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Hoverboard):

> **A hoverboard was similar in appearance to a skateboard but underwent a hover conversion**.
>
> [image: Hoverboard]
>
> [**Hover Conversion:**](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Hover_conversion)
>
> A hover conversion was an application to a ground vehicle to enable it to fly. For the DeLorean time machine ... the [hoverwheels](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Hoverwheel) would fold down when in flight ...
>
> [image: Flying DeLorean] <sup>[[Source](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/32125/back-to-future-predicts-future)]</sup>
>
> [Flying circuits](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_circuit) were inserted into the vehicle.
>
> **It is unknown if there was another source of lift other than thrust, such as anti-gravity or magnetism. Considering the loads that some vehicles produced, and that thrust was not always applied when a vehicle first lifted up, it is feasible that these alternatives could have been used**.

---

[**Mattel Will Finally Release The Hoverboard From ‘Back To The Future’**](http://www.slashfilm.com/mattel-release-hoverboard-back-to-the-future/)

> But before you get too excited, remember that just as when Nike released the limited edition sneaker run, they noted that the self-lacing technology wouldn’t be ready until 2015, the same is true with hover technology — its just not quite ready for primetime just yet.
>
> **The movie-accurate 1:1 Hoverboard replica will ship for Christmas 2012.**
>
> [image: Hoverboard Ad]

Answer (score -1):

Strong neodimium permament magnets don't need a source of energy.

Those magnets are composed as a halbach array.

Comment: So the tarmac over which it hovers is magnetic?